# In Maya python, run command even if an object (part of a string) doesn't exist in the scene

Tags: python, maya

I have this code

```
cmds.select('cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'mouse', hierarchy=True, r=True)
min_time = cmds.playbackOptions(q=True, min=True)
max_time = cmds.playbackOptions(q=True, max=True)
cmds.bakeResults(simulation=True, time=(min_time, max_time))
```

If, for example, the "dog" object doesn't exist, the command won't run because it is looking for that object. But I do want the command to select all the rest of the objects even if one of them doesn't exist, so that it continues with the baking with the others. To sum up, how can I do to run it even if on of the objects listed don't exist in the scene? I need this script to run in different scenes where sometimes not all of these objects will exist. Thanks.

PS. these objects are only an example, I have like 20 specific objects I must always include in this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cmds.ls` to pass a series of object names to it. It will return a list of objects it finds in the scene, so that it will filter out the objects that don't exist. In general, most commands don't require you to pass a selection so you don't have to select anything at all. It's a bad habit to get into since it forces the scene to redraw and it's extra overhead that can easily be avoid. Instead, we can pass the results directly to `cmds.bakeResults`:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

min_time = cmds.playbackOptions(q=True, min=True)
max_time = cmds.playbackOptions(q=True, max=True)

objs = cmds.ls('cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'mouse')  # Returns a new list of objects it finds.

if objs:  # Only bake if there is at least one object.
    cmds.bakeResults(objs, simulation=True, time=(min_time, max_time))  # Pass new list as first argument.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not aware I could have the "if there is at least one object" option in the if statement. This will be useful for the other stages of my script. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you can do *implicit* if statements for most value types. `cmds.ls` returns a list, so if it ends up returning an empty list it's equivalent to checking `if objs != []`. A list with at least one item will pass the if statement. Likewise, you can do the same for an empty dictionary, an empty string, and even an integer that's 0.

Comment: I appreciate a lot the explanation, much more clear now :)